# Subset calculation in infinite/(dynamic) Universe set of alphanummeric elements

Tags: algorithm, performance, math, encoding, functional-programming

Given a infinite set/Universe (U) of alphanumeric elements and a family (F) of subsets of (U).

Calculate/Group all related subsets in (F), where all elements are covered or less, see example.

The Universe is not really infinite, but very large, approximately 59Mil elements and growing. Family (F) subsets, are not constant either, approximately 13Mil elements and growing as well.

Example:

U = {`9b3745e9`,`ab70de17`,`1c410139`,`44038bbf`,`9c610bb`,...,N}

F1 = {`9b3745e9`,07ee0220}

F2 = {`9b3745e9`,`ab70de17`,99b5d738}

F3 = {99b5d738,07ee0220}

F4 = {`9b3745e9`,`ab70de17`,`1c410139`}

F4<sub>calculate()</sub>={F2(2),F1(1)}

Of cause you can do it on brutal iteration, but over time it is not the optimal solution (NP-complete problem).

Any ideas how this can be solved more efficient? Encoding subsets, while using a element/vector Codebook that is larger than Universe, for instance 70Mil or 100Mil. But I'm not sure about calculation.

Comment: Define "related". Define "growing". And please decide whether you are solving the very large or the infinite case.

Comment: Permanent growing of Universe needs to be consider, how fast it is growing its not so relevant for the solution. Because the date is growing permanently it would be easier to view the Universe as infinite. But maybe I'm also very wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems based on the example that "related" subsets are subsets that contain at least one common element. In the example, F4 has two shared elements, 0x9b3746e9 (shared with F1) and 0xab70de17 and 0x9b3746e9 shared with F2. The numbers in parentheses denote the number of shared elements (F2(2) = 2 shared elements with F2). Assuming this intepretation:

> This is obviously not an NP-complete
>   problem but a simple case of indexing.
>   In a hash table, link every element of
>   U (59 * 10<sup>6</sup>) to a list of
>   subsets that contain them (e.g.
>   0x9b3746e9 -> { F1, F2, F4 } ). When
>   finding the related subsets of a given
>   subset, iterate through the elements
>   of U in the subset, and lookup the
>   hash table for every element. Iterate
>   through the lists, and you find the
>   related subsets. This is a fast
>   operation and there's nothing
>   NP-complete in it.

However another interpretation of the question is that this is an instance of SET COVER combinatorial optimization problem. This is indeed NP-complete.

Comment: Solution you mentioned was originally implemented. To save iteration cycles subsets are getting weighted. But I'm still looking for an encoding solution, to overcome the iteration of subsets completely. Thanks!